# Use new attribute values to validate before_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

In my project, I have a model called `PaymentCondition` and another called `PaymentPortion`.
`PaymentCondition` **has_many** `payment_portions` and `PaymentPortion` **belongs_to** `payment_condition`.

When I create a *new* `PaymentCondition`, I have this method that creates **n** `payment_portions`. Being **n** the value of a `:amount` attribute from `PaymentCondition`.

If I create a new `PaymentCondition` with `amount: 2`, for instance, I'd have 2 `payment_portions`.

So far, so good.

My problem:

I'm using a **nested form** to this view, so I can edit everything at once.

`PaymentCondition` has a attribute called `catchments`.

`PaymentPortion` has a attribute called `catchment`.

**Before** submiting this form, I'd like to check if the **sum** of `PaymentPortion.catchment` is equal to `PaymentCondition.catchments`. If not, I must raise an error.

As for now, I can't get the new values of `PaymentCondition` before saving it...

I'm doing this inside `payment_conditions_controller`:

```
before_update :check_catchments

def check_catchments 
  errors.add(:catchments, "Values must check") unless catchments_check? || new_record? 
end

def catchments_check?
  catchment == portion_catchments
end

def portion_catchments
  payment_portions.sum(:catchments)
end
```

Using **sum()**, I get only the values that are on the database. What I need are the values that are being send...

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be working directly in the controller is an option? You can use methods like 'build' or 'first_or_initialize' to get\create AR objects. And then just validate them in the controller and save the data if necessary.

Comment: That's the first thing I thought about, actually. The second one would be doing this validation with javascript on the view... Since all my other validations are being made inside de Models, I thought there would be some way to do this.